# How to get all cookies with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, google-chrome-extension

For a small project of mine I am trying to get a list of all cookies of a website and analyze them later on which flags they and/or are missing. I look at a website through the inspection tool and I am seeing a lot more cookies than what I get from my code, presumably due to the same-origin-policy? Anyways my question is, if there is a way to request a website in JS and get the entirety of the cookies? I am also open to new ideas if there is another way to test or find out the flags of the cookies of any website.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
console.log(headers);
```

EDIT: The answer to the problem was `chrome.cookies.getAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) documentation from Mozilla website ?

I can just use `document.cookie` to retrieve all cookies stored on your web browser

Comment: I have tried using document.cookie, but there are still some cookies that are not listed. The website I tested it on was YouTube just cause I happened to have it open in a tab.

Comment: You won't be able to see HttpOnly cookies with Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies

Comment: @Steve In the end I accidentally stumbled on chrome.cookies.getAll() since apparently extensions can have higher permissions that allow to see httponly cookies.